# How to get all products with Qty in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, product-collection, stock-status

I am trying to get `all products` with it's `stock qty` in magento2. 
please let me know if anybody have solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all `products` with `qty` using below code

```
 <?php

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');

    $collection = $productCollection->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->load();

    foreach ($collection as $product){

            echo $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
            echo $product->getName();
    }  

    ?>
```

Comment: Don't use object manager directly if dependency possible.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using Object Manager, use dependency structure for good practise.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
*/
protected $productFactory;

public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productFactory
    .....
)
{
    .....
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    .....
}
public function execute()
{
    $product = $this->productFactory->create();
    $product->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);
    $product = $product->joinField('qty',
            'cataloginventory_stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left'
        )->joinTable('cataloginventory_stock_item', 'product_id = entity_id', ['stock_status' => 'is_in_stock'])
        ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
        ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'DESC')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
        ->load();
    return $product;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Collection stock item from Resource Model**

```
$resource = $objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Item');
$select = $resource->getConnection()->select()->from($resource->getMainTable());
$stockItems = $resource->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
foreach($stockItems as $_item){
    var_dump($_item->getData());
}
```

**if you have product object then just use following:**

```
var_dump($_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getData());
```

I hope this will help